# Aspose OCR - Not Recognising Image

Tags: c#, ocr, aspose

I'm playing around with Aspose OCR and it's reading images with white backgrounds and black text fine. However, anything with a black or different colour background it does not read.

Any idea how to get around this?

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SendKeys.Send("{PRTSC}");
            Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image = img;




           if (img != null)
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();

                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // put here the image format 
                ms.Position = 0;

                ocr.Image = ImageStream.FromStream(ms, ImageStreamFormat.Jpg);

                if (ocr.Process()) // Start processing it 
                {
                    label1.Text = "Text: " + ocr.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following line of code. Further to update you that development on processing of color back ground image feature is in-progress.

```
ocr.Config.ProcessColoredBackground = true;
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.